# When do we switch load balancing algorithm in cloud computing?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability

I have setup a HAproxy load balancer and I have a question is when do I need to switch load balancing algorithm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this depends on your requirements.

Take a look into the documentation [balance](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#4-balance) to know which algorithm is the right one for your setup.

Maybe the Blog post [Test Driving “Power of Two Random Choices” Load Balancing](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/power-of-two-load-balancing/) can help you also to understand the balancing algorithms in HAProxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the profile of HAProxy to switch.you shoulod only modify the setting items: bakcend->balance, whicn can be roundrobin, source, static-rr, etc.